SQLAlchemy - Tables are not created by Database class
I am struggling to automatically create tables using SQLAlchemy for Postgresql database.
In my module I defined a base.py:
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    # Ensure all models use the public schema by default
    metadata = MetaData(schema='public')
    __abstract__ = True

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        """Converts the fields (columns) of a class to a dictionary without the '_sa_instance_state' key."""
        return {field.name: getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c}

    @classmethod
    def get_count(cls, session: Session) -> int:
        """Get the count of rows in the table."""
        return session.query(cls).count()

Then I defined a table in my models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, Integer, Float, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from .base import Base

class SensorData(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sensor_data'
    trip_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True)
    acceleration_x = Column(Float)
    # Other fields...


and a Database object in my database.py:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from .models import SensorData  # Models imported after Base
from .base import Base

class Database:
    def __init__(self):
        from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
        url_object = URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
            username="username",
            password="password",
            host="localhost",
            port=5432,
            database="database"
        )

        self.engine = create_engine(url_object, echo=True)
        self.metadata = MetaData(schema='public')
        
        # Explicitly bind metadata and engine to the Base class
        Base.metadata = self.metadata
        Base.metadata.bind = self.engine
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)  # Table creation

In other parts of my code I would like to create the database object, and create the tables if they don't exist yet (in the public schema)
    db = Database()

All code executes without errors, however, no tables are being created. The database user also should have sufficient privileges. From what Ive read the order of importing the classes is important, but I am not sure how ensure everything is imported correctly with my current code setup?

Before you create tables you need to initialize all the child class declarations of your Base class
if you have next structure
project
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── database.py
├── __init__.py
└── main.py

you can do next in your core.__init__.py
from .models import *
from .database import Database

db = Database()

then in your main
from core import db


I tried it, but that did not work :/

Okay, I finally found the error. In my Database class i instantiated another MetaData object, instead of using the one from my Base class..
